# A property of the ring of integers of cyclotomic fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Let $t$ be a positive integer and consider $\mathbb Q(\zeta_t)$ a cyclotomic field. It is known that its ring of integer is $R=\mathbb Z[\zeta_t]$. I would like to know why there exists a nonzero prime ideal $P$ of $R$ that does not contain $t$.

Probably it is not so difficult to prove it, so I would appreciate some hints about it.

Comment: *Nonzero* prime ideal, I assume.  Otherwise, I have a candidate: $(0)$ :).

Comment: Anyway, if $R$ denotes any ring of integers, the Jacobson radical of $R$ is $0$: hence every element of $R$ does not belong to some maximal ideal.

Comment: $R$ is Dedekind, so $tR$ is a product of finitely many primes.

Comment: @Crostul Why the Jacobson radical is $0$?

Comment: @user26857 Your point is that if $Q$ is a prime ideal not in the factorization of $tR$ then it cannot contain $t$ since otherwise $Q$ would divide $tR$ and so it would be in its factorization, right?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but try considering a prime $p$ that doesn't divide $t$. $(p)$ might not be prime but there are primes above it.

Comment: I don't understand: where is the ideal $(p)$? In $R$? Then if $P\supset (p)$ in $R$, why $t\notin P$?

Comment: $P$ lying over $(p)$ means that $P \cap \mathbb{Z}=(p).$ Thus, if $t \in P,$ then $t \in P\cap \mathbb{Z}=(p)$.